# Understanding return [0,size-1][nums[0]<nums[size-1]] in Python

Tags: python, list

While working on a simple coding question, writing a function `findPeakElement`, I came across the following code:

```
def findPeakElement(self, nums):
     size = len(nums)
     for x in range(1,size-1):
         if nums[x] > nums[x-1] and nums[x] > nums[x+1]:
            return x

     return [0,size-1][nums[0]<nums[size-1]]
```

What is the meaning of last line?

Comment: can you share a sample input?

Answer (score 9):

That last row is an obscure way of writing an `if then else` expression.

- `[0, size-1]` creates a list of two elements.
- `nums[0] < nums[size-1]` returns either `True` or `False`
- when used as a list index, this `True/False` is implicitly converted into `1` or `0`.
- and by that, either `size-1` or `0` is picked from the list.

A clearer way to write it is:

```
return size - 1 if nums[0] < nums[size - 1] else 0
```

Answer (score 5):

The first set of brackets constructs a list, the second set of bracket indexes the list.

```
[0,size-1][nums[0]<nums[size-1]]
^^^^^^^^^^
# constructs a list

[0,size-1][nums[0]<nums[size-1]]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          # indexes the list
```

For example, let's say `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Then `size = 4`. The constructed list will be

```
[0, size-1] == [0, 3]
```

Given the list `nums` above, the second set of brackets will evaluate to

```
nums[0] < nums[size-1]    ==    1 < 4
                          ==    True
```

...which in turn, will index the list

```
[0, size-1][True]    ==    size-1
```

---

In some circles, it is a code-golfing technique as it emulates an if-statement. In short, it is *approximately* equivalent to

```
if nums[0] < nums[size - 1]:
    return size - 1
else:
    return 0
```

It's only *approximately* equivalent because both tokens `0` and `size-1` are evaluated when the list is constructed. But they are not with the if-statement.

For example:

```
print([0, 1/0][0])
```

will raise an error when the program reaches the line. However...

```
if 0:
    print(1/0)
else:
    print(0)
```

The above will only raise an error if the program executes `print(1/0)`.